# How do I check if a color has a certain amount of red (visual basic 2010)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make an application where it detects if your mouse is on an object that is red. Not 100% red, but red.

```
currentclr = myBmp.GetPixel(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
```

this is what I use to find what color my mouse is on

For example, let's say I hover my mouse over a red object, if I convert it to string, it looks something like this

```
Color [A=232, R=201, G=15, B=15]
```

How do I check if the R is greater than 150?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
   if (currentclr.R > 150)
```